# Changing the color of environments in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, environments

I have just started lerning Latex. So, it is possible that the following doubt is very easy.

I have to do a presentation with Beamer. I know that there exist specific comands to theorems, definitions, examples... I wonder if it is possible to modify those environments and change its default color. That is can I use the Theorem environment in such a way that the color of the block is green instead of blue?
In the following example I wanto to change the color of the block to red.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
  $a^+b^2=c^2$
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which themes you use to create your presentation?

Comment: A very, very useful resource is http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf --- you can find everything tunable there.

Comment: @leandriis Ok, I have just edited it!

Comment: @Rmano Is it correct now?

Comment: Perfect! (this is why I upvoted yor comment and removed my comment...;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetheme{madrid}

\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=example text,fg=white,bg=example text.fg!75!black}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
  $a^+b^2=c^2$
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For a yellow colored "Teorema" block, please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetheme{madrid}

\newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=example text,fg=black,bg=yellow!75!black}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=yellow!10}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{theo}[Pythagoras]
  $a^+b^2=c^2$
\end{theo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have a doubt. How could I change the color to yellow? I don't see where is the specific command to change the color

Comment: @mathlife `texdoc xcolor` or https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf

Comment: Finally, my last doubt: How can I change in that environment the word "Theorem" by "Teorema"?

Comment: @mathlife: I have edited my answer according to your requests.

Comment: @leandriis A lot of thanks!!!!!!!